# Single Rotate Method

Tags: javascript, css, simulation, animation

I just started coding a simulation-like application. It's about our solar system. Right now, I'm working on rotating the moon. I have this `constructor`

```
function Mass(elm) {
    if (typeof elm == "string") {
        this.elm = document.getElementById(elm);
    } else {
        this.elm = elm;
    }
    this.width      = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this.elm).width, 10);
    this.height     = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this.elm).height, 10);
    this.top        = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this.elm).top, 10);
    this.left       = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this.elm).left, 10);
    this.radius     = this.width / 2;
    this.origin     = {
        x : this.left + this.width / 2,
        y : this.top + this.height / 2,
    };
    this.angle = 0;
    this.rotation   = function () {
        if (this.angle >= 360) { this.angle = 0; }
        this.angle += 1;
        this.elm.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + this.angle + "deg)";
    };
    this.rotate = function (mthd) {
        setInterval(mthd, 100);
    }
}
var moon = new Mass("moon");
moon.rotate("moon.rotation()");
```

The issue I'm having is this `moon.rotate("moon.rotation()");`. There are two methods, and the way I call them is um.. weird? I want to use a single method to rotate the object. Like `moon.rotate()`.

I tried a few ways to put the code in just one method, but couldn't figure it out.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/e8Nry/)

---

<sup>Even though I'm done with the problem mentioned in this question, I wanted to add something, the full code. In case if anyone is interested.</sup>

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/e8Nry/7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, you don't want to pass a string to `setInterval()`; better to use a function. You can bind that function to the object's context, so it'll call the right thing.

For another, aim for less ambiguous names. `rotation` should probably be `updateRotation`, since that's what it does. And `rotate` should likely be `startRotating` (and they you could have an equivalent `stopRotating`).

That be something like:

```
this.startRotating = function () {
  var self = this; // to maintain the object's context
  setInterval(function () {
    self.updateRotation();
  }, 100);
};
```

However, if you're planning to add more planets etc., it would probably be nicer to have one central timer that calls an `update` function on all your objects.

And I'd also define a "proper" prototype for all this, and extract some general logic/avoid repetition:

```
// extract this logic, since it's generally useful
function getElement(element) {
  if (typeof element == "string") {
    return document.getElementById(element);
  }
  return element;
}

function Mass(element, angularVelocity) { // added the rotation speed as an arg
  var computedStyle;

  this.element = getElement(element);

  // fetch this once
  computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this.element);

  this.width  = parseInt(computedStyle.width, 10);
  this.height = parseInt(computedStyle.height, 10);
  this.top    = parseInt(computedStyle.top, 10);
  this.left   = parseInt(computedStyle.left, 10);
  this.radius = this.width / 2;

  this.origin = {
    x: this.left + this.radius, // you just calculated the radius; might as well use it here
    y: this.top + this.radius
  };

  this.angularVelocity = angularVelocity;
  this.rotation = 0;
}

// make nice prototype
Mass.prototype = {
  update: function () {
    this.rotation = (this.rotation + this.angularVelocity) % 360;
    this.element.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + this.rotation + "deg)";
  }
};

// do the timer magic outside the object
var moon = new Mass("moon", 1.0),
    timer;

timer = setInterval(function () {
  moon.update();
}, 100);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R22JA/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went over my code after seeing your examples. Fixed the problem now. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/e8Nry/1/)

Comment: @akinuri You could just set a negative rotation speed, instead of having the `ccw` argument. The modulus trick (`angle = (angle + speed) % 360`) in the code above will work for negative values, so you can get rid of a lot of code

Comment: Oh, indeed. Changed the code. Just few methods away from perfect. Gonna create a method to place the moon into earth's orbit. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/e8Nry/2/)